# When using multiple inheritance in Perl is there a way to indicate which SUPER function to use?

Tags: perl

As per the title, I'm working on an awkward bit of code that makes use of multiple inheritance and requires that the two `SUPER` functions both be called. Is there a way of indicating to Perl which of the two parent classes I want to run the function from? Using `$self->SUPER::foo($bar);` only runs the first matching function in `@ISA` as per the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Inheritance).

The following gives an idea of how the classes are inherited:

```
          [Base Class]
               |
 ----------------------------
 |                          |
[A]                        [B]
 |                          |
 ----------------------------
               |
              [C]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just specify it:

```
$self->A::foo($bar)
```

or

```
$self->B::foo($bar)
```

You may also want to look at [mro](https://metacpan.org/module/mro).

Comment: When I saw this I thought it was something that I had already tried, turns out that I had, but I also hadn't fully resolved things, i.e. `$self->A::foo()` vs. `$self->Package::A::foo()`.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work in all cases: Assume `foo` uses a method that is redefined in the current class. Then such call does not use dynamic binding. I have a case where that causes a wrong setup.

Comment: @U.Windl not sure what you mean by dynamic binding.  foo will receive $self as its first parameter, and any method calls on that will behave normally.  If that doesn't do what you want, you need to reconsider your inheritance, and maybe use objects of other classes as attributes instead.

Comment: @ysth See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76786415/6607497; maybe it still works and I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options.

If there are always just two candidate superclasses, you can force `@ISA` to be searched in both directions, so

```
$self->SUPER::method;
{
    local @ISA = reverse @ISA;
    $self->SUPER::method;
}
```

or, if you want to do something more clever, you can build the names of all the superclasses' methods at runtime:

```
my ($caller) = (caller(0))[3] =~ /([^:]+)\z/;
for my $super (@ISA) {
    my $method = join '::', $super, $caller;
    $self->$method if exists &$method;
}
```

The first line fetches the name of the currently-executing method and strips off the package name information to leave just the bare name. Then it is appended to each package name in `@ISA` and the method is called if it exists.

Comment: If I had to maintain that, I rather think I would shivel into a little ball like a leach someone had poured salt out on. :)

Comment: I belive I have finally understood `local`.

Comment: @tchrist: It's as readable as I can make it. Surely the problem is with the requirement rather than the solution?

Comment: My problem lies not with legibility but with the notion of diddling `@ISA`. That `local` is dynamically scoped, so during calls to "the other SUPER" it will still be flipped. I much prefer the `next::method` etc stuff from `use mro` especially with, or even the `EVERY::foo` vs `EVERY::LAST::foo` from `use NEXT`. If you're flipping left and right or breadth versus depth, think super carefully about whether there isn't a more established and maintainable way of realizing your real goal than through hacking `@ISA` during the dynamic scope as that has terrible side-effects. ysth’s answer’s good.

Comment: @tchrist: Thank you. That's useful. I'm really not familiar with `mro`, but it really should be in my toolbox, and I wasn't even aware of `NEXT` despite it being a core module.