# How to call a grandparent method in perl

Tags: perl

I was recently needing to call the *grandparent* of a class. Let's say I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

package Superhero;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  return bless {}, $class;
}

sub SaveWorld {
    my $self = shift;
    my %args = (
        hero => "nobody",
        @_
        );
    my $hero = $args{hero};

    say "$hero saved the world again";
    $self->{status} = "World saved by $hero";
}

sub WorldStatus() {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{status};
}

package Superman;
use parent -norequire, qw(Superhero);

sub SaveWorld {
    my $self = shift;
    my %args = ( hero => "superman" );

    $self->SUPER::SaveWorld(%args);
}
```

and wanted a new class `Spiderman` that was like Superman but slightly different:

```
package Spiderman;
use parent -norequire, qw(Superman);

sub SaveWorld {
    my $self = shift;
    my $hero = "spiderman";

    ??? # Call Superhero->SaveWorld    
}
```

for being called as:

```
my $hero = Spiderman->new;
$hero->SaveWorld();
say $hero->WorldStatus();
```

It seems quite bad documented how to perform that `???` call.

Something like `$self->SUPER::SUPER::SaveWorld($hero)` doesn't work (it would look for a package called "SUPER::SUPER").

To make matters worse, the parent itself was dynamic, so a literal `$self->Superhero::SaveWorld(%args);` was not possible.

The class itself can be easily extracted with `my $class = $Superman::ISA[0];`, though.

A static call could be achieved with something like:

```
my $eval = $class . '::SaveWorld($self, %args)';
eval $eval;
```

which was not working, though (it seems to work as expected in this example, though).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
$self->Superhero::SaveWorld(%args);
```

Doing so would just compound a broken design. You should fix your design rather than using this.  It's unclear what the fix would be because your example makes no sense: A spider man isn't a super man.

Comment: This anwer misses the condition that the parent class (Superman) itself has a dynamic parent. See the part «so a literal $self->Superhero::SaveWorld(%args); was not possible» (note: by error the original version used a different parameter). Otherwise, yes, this would be the right way to call it if you always have the same grandparent.

Comment: @Angel, There's no such thing as a dynamic parent class. A Spiderman is always a Superhero. If it can change, it's not a parent class, and you're misusing inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use a string with the method name.

As found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15415554/3697633) by Borodin:

```
my $method = join '::', $class, "SaveWorld";
```

or just

```
my $method = "${class}::SaveWorld";
```

(but note the `${class}` to not go over the `::`, otherwise it tries `${class::SaveWorld}`!)

Thus,

```
package Spiderman;
use parent -norequire, qw(Superman);

sub SaveWorld {
    my $self = shift;
    my %args = ( hero => "spiderman" );

    my $class = $Superman::ISA[0];
    say "I am looking for $class";
    my $method = join '::', $class, "SaveWorld";
    $self->$method(%args);
}
```