# Perl multiple inheritance, inheriting the same method name twice: How to use the right method correctly?

Tags: perl, methods, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Well, I shouldn't use Perl using multiple inheritance, but I did.
Consider the following code sketch (`$self` denotes the current object):

```perl
package A;
sub f { ... }
sub _init { ...; $self->f; ... }
sub new { ... $self->_init ... }

package B;
sub _init { ... }
sub new { ... $self->_init ... }

package C;
sub f { ... }
our @ISA = qw(A B);
sub new
{
    my $class = $_[0];
    my $self = ...;
    bless $self, $class;
    ??? call A:_init using $self, call B:_init using $self, setup C's attributes
}
```

The challenge for `C->new` is how to integrate the constructors from `A` and `B` (assuming `_init` does all the setup except blessing and allocating the object).
Using `$self->SUPER::_init` could use only one of the two inherited methods, and it's not very obvious *which* (probably from the package listed in `@ISA` first).

The other thing is how to make sure that `A::_init` uses dynamic binding for `f`, i.e.: use `C::f`? Specifically using `A::_init($self)` does *not*.
Specifically `C` could also have its own `_init`, and even `A`and `B` could inherit more packages...

### A compilable example

Here is a code sample that does compile, and it demonstrates what should happen (the commented statements are from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76786760/6607497 already):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
require 5.018_000;
use strict;
use warnings;

package P1;

sub f($)
{
    $_[0]->[0] = 1;
}

sub _init($)
{
    $_[0]->f();
}

sub new($)
{
    my $class = $_[0];
    my $self = [];

    $#$self = 0;
    bless $self, $class;
    $self->_init();
    return $self;
}

package P2;

sub _init($)
{
    $_[0]->[0] = 2;
}

sub new($)
{
    my $class = $_[0];
    my $self = [];

    $#$self = 0;
    bless $self, $class;
    _self->_init();
    return $self;
}

package P3;

our @ISA = qw(P1 P2);

BEGIN {
    use Exporter qw(import);
}

sub f($)
{
    $_[0]->[1] = 3;
}

sub _init($)
{
    $_[0]->[2] = 4;
}

sub new($)
{
    my $class = $_[0];
    my $self = [];

    $#$self = 2;
    bless $self, $class;
    #$self->P1::_init();
    #$self->P2::_init();
    $self->_init();
    return $self;
}

package min;

my $o = P3->new();
$DB::single = 1;
print $o, "\n"; # prevent optimizing $o away too early
```

So while `P1::f` sets `$self->[0] = 1`, `P3::f` sets `$self->[1] = 3`, so `P1`'s `_init`, when called from a `P3` object, should not set  `$self->[0] = 1`, but set `$self->[1] = 3`.

So the result should be:

```perl-db
  DB<1> x $o
0  P3=ARRAY(0xbd27e8)
   0  2
   1  3
   2  4
```

Comment: Note that "B" isn't the best class name to use in examples, because there is a core Perl module called "B".

Comment: The actual class names aren't `A`, `B`, and `C`, but for the sake of illustration it should be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child class can do this:

```perl
package C;

our @ISA = qw(A B);

sub new {
    my $class = $_[0];
    my $self = ...;
    bless $self, $class;
    $self->A::_init();
    $self->B::_init();
    return $self;
}
```

If C had its own `_init` method, I'd write it like this:

```perl
package C;

our @ISA = qw(A B);

sub new {
    my $class = $_[0];
    my $self = ...;
    bless $self, $class;
    $self->_init;
    return $self;
}

sub _init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->A::_init();
    $self->B::_init();
    ...; # more initialization
}
```

One of your concerns seems to be making sure that `$object->f` uses dynamic binding. If you use the arrow operator (`->`) to call a method it will *always* use dynamic binding.

So if you called `A::_init($object)` (static binding) but within `A::_init` a `$self->f` call happens, that call will use dynamic binding.

So in my examples, why do I use `$self->A::_init()` instead of `A::_init($self)`? Because the former syntax uses dynamic binding — it just starts the method resolution at "A" instead of starting at "C".

A more convoluted example:

```perl
package Grandparent {
  use Class::Tiny;  # provides `new`

  sub init {
    my $self = shift;
    print "From Grandparent\n";
  }
}

package Parent1 {
  use parent -norequire, 'Grandparent';  # provides `@ISA`
}

package Parent2 {
  use Class::Tiny;

  sub init {
    my $self = shift;
    print "From Parent2\n";
  }
}

package Child {
  use parent -norequire, 'Parent1', 'Parent2';

  sub init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->Parent1::init();
    $self->Parent2::init();
    print "From Child\n";
  }
}

my $eg = Child->new;
$eg->init;
```

Note in this example, `Child` inherits from two parent classes. Its `init` method calls the `init` method via each of its parents, including the `Parent1` class which **does not define an `init` method of its own** but inherits it from `Grandparent`.

Comment: The good news is that your answer works; the bad news is that in my original program there must be a different bug (still to be found) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to call different `init()` methods in your class hierarchy explicitly, this seems to be an anti-pattern. If your `@ISA` changes somewhere in the hierarchy you need to adjust code in other places to keep your program working as expected.

Perl has a module called [mro](https://perldoc.perl.org/mro) in core which offers the possibility to switch your classes method resolution order between dfs (default) and [c3](https://perldoc.perl.org/mro#What-is-C3?).
Even if you want to keep the mro at dfs you can use [next::method()](https://perldoc.perl.org/mro#next::method) and [maybe::next method()](https://perldoc.perl.org/mro#maybe::next::method) which always use c3 mro to resolve the method calls.

The following example adds a common parent class with inheritable constructor and init methods which are called in correct order. Note that it is common to have init code do the work in parent classes first.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use mro;
package GP;

sub new($)
{
    my $class = $_[0];
    my $self = [];
    bless $self, $class;
    $self->_init();
    return $self;
}

sub _init
{
    say 'GP::init called';
    say 'GP::init: do work';
}

package P1;
our @ISA = 'GP';
sub f($)
{
    say 'P1::f called';
}

sub _init($)
{
    my $self = shift;
    say 'P1::init called';
    $self->maybe::next::method(@_);
    say 'P1::init: do work, call ->f()';
    $self->f();
}


package P2;
our @ISA = 'GP';
sub _init($)
{
    my $self = shift;
    say 'P2::init called';
    $self->maybe::next::method(@_);
    say 'P2::init: do work';
}

package P3;

our @ISA = qw(P1 P2);

sub f($)
{
    say 'P3::f called';
}

sub _init($)
{
    my $self = shift;
    say 'P3::init called';
    $self->maybe::next::method(@_);
    say 'P3::init: do work';
}

package main;

my $o = P3->new;


# P3::init called
# P1::init called
# P2::init called
# GP::init called
# GP::init: do work
# P2::init: do work
# P1::init: do work, call ->f()
# P3::f called
# P3::init: do work
```

Comment: "*While it is possible to call different init() methods in your class hierarchy explicitly, this seems to be an anti-pattern. If your @ISA changes somewhere in the hierarchy you need to adjust code in other places to keep your program working as expected.*": Yo are right, but I wanted to punish myself using combined multiple and repeated inheritance with array objects ;-)